# Register same service with different configuration

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-7.0

A class needs to talk to sFTP at different host. The `SftpService` is a the wrapper class, so now I need two of them that are registered with different sFTP config.

I'm trying to do it in this way - having `A_SftpService` and `B_SftpService` extends `SftpService`, then passing corresponding config to the base.

I was wondering is this a good approach or what is the better way of doing this?

Code snippet as below:

Config in appsettings:

```
"SftpSettings": {
   "SrcA": {
      "Host": "",
      "Username": "",
      "Password": ""
   },
   "SrcB": {
      "Host": "",
      "Username": "",
      "Password": ""
   }
}
```

POCO of the sftp config:

```
public class SftpSettings
{
    public Dictionary<string, SftpConfigs> Configs { get; set; }
}

public class SftpConfigs
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Service classes:

```
public class SftpService : ISftpService
{
    private readonly SftpConfigs _sftpConfigs;

    public SftpService(SftpConfigs configs) {
       _sftpConfigs = configs;
    }
    
    public void Upload(Stream fileStream) {
       using var sftpClient = new SftpClient(_sftpConfigs.Host, 22, _sftpConfigs.Username, _sftpConfigs.Password);
       ...
    }

    public Stream Download(string filePath) {
       using var sftpClient = new SftpClient(_sftpConfigs.Host, 22, _sftpConfigs.Username, _sftpConfigs.Password);
       ...
    }

}

public class SftpServiceForSrcA : SftpService
{
    public SftpServiceForSrcA(SftpSettings sftpSettings) : base(sftpSettings["SrcA"]) {}
}

public class SftpServiceForSrcB : SftpService
{
    public SftpServiceForSrcB(SftpSettings sftpSettings) : base(sftpSettings["SrcB"]) {}
}
```

Consumer class:

```
public class ConsumerClass {
    private readonly ISftpService _sftpServiceForSrcA;
    private readonly ISftpService _sftpServiceForSrcB;


    public void Upload(Stream fileStream) {
        // need to upload to SrcA sFTP
        _sftpServiceForSrcA.Upload(fileStream);
    }

    public void Download(string path) {
        // need to upload to SrcB sFTP
        var stream = _sftpServiceForSrcB.Download(path);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```